# Can I buy my plane ticket to exit the US to Mexico?

Tags: usa, proof-of-onward-travel, chilean-citizens

I'm from Chile, and I'm flying from Colombia to San Francisco, I need to buy a ticket to exit the US, can this ticket be to Mexico? 
I will be staying only a month and a half in the United States.

Comment: Are you entering under Visa Waiver?  Are you planning to come back to the US from Mexico?

Comment: Are you trying to reset the clock by leaving the US ? If so going to Mexico won't work

Comment: No, I have a visa, but I'm travelling with a friend from germany, she has the Visa Waiver. We are not planning to return to the US, we want to continue travelling then down through central America. The thing is that I don't know if we will have problems entering the US, with an exit ticket to Mexico.

Comment: What issues are you expecting ?

Comment: The only thing you have to be aware of is that travel to Mexico doesn't reset the VWP clock.  Other than that there is no issue.

Comment: I'm from Chile, I travelled on 2013 to the US, before the Visa waiver was available for us. So I still have a visa..so do you think it would be enough for my friends to buy a ticket to mexico and then a bus ticket to get out of mexico?

Answer (score 8):

In general, citizens of Chile do not require a visa to enter the US (and can instead enter via VWP with an approved ESTA), however in the comments you've stated that you have a Visa, whilst your travelling companion from Germany does not and will use ESTA.  Thus there's 2 different answers...

With a Visa - There is officially no need for a return/onward ticket when entering the US with a visa. However even with a visa, your entry to the US is at the discretion of the border officials. If they believe you intend to over-stay your entry then they can deny your entry.  Having an onward ticket will reduce the chances of this occurring.

Without a Visa - When entering under the VWP program there is a requirement to have an onward or return ticket. If that ticket is to either Canada/Mexico (or several countries in the Caribbean), then you ALSO need a ticket onward from that country to another country that does not border the US (unless you are a resident there).

So for you, a ticket is not required but may be advised - and Mexico will be fine.  For your companion, a ticket is required - and Mexico will NOT be suitable without also having a ticket from Mexico to somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have any authoritative references?

Answer (score 5):

When you enter the US, whether on a visa waiver or visa, you'll likely be asked to show proof that you intend to leave and not try to stay. For you any valid ticket out of the US should do, including to Mexico. For your friend however, a flight that ends in Mexico [won't do](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.2) and I recommend they get an additional ticket out of Mexico to be safe.

You should be aware though, that this doesn't reset the VWP clock for your friend. In case they return to the US their stay in Mexico will be counted in their 90 days.

Comment: Timatic (the system most airlines use to determine visa/VWP eligibility)  states "A return/onward ticket (or electronic ticket record) must be to a final destination country other than Canada, Mexico or contiguous (adjacent) countries or territories situated in or bordering the Caribbean Sea". It's also in the VWP legislation, I'm just too lazy to look it up

Comment: [8 CFR 217.2(c)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.2) explicitly requires "a round trip ticket that will transport the traveler out of the United States to any other foreign port or place **as long as the trip does not terminate in contiguous territory or an adjacent island**" (with exception for residents of that contiguour-territory-or-adjacent-island).

Comment: Would it work if you have a ticket from the US to Mexico, and then a further ticket from Mexico to some more distant place?  Or is it just impossible to do a visit X -> US -> Mexico -> X trip under VWP?

Comment: @NateEldredge yeah it seems that you need an additional ticket leaving Mexico, if you're from a VWP country and have a ticket to Mexico

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on "might be questioned about that".  Would it *just* be a matter of additional questions to confirm they are eventually planning to leave, or is there a significant chance they would be denied entry altogether?  What about the Timatic issue, would they even be able to board the flight?

Comment: @NateEldredge if Timatic flagged it they probably won't let them board, for admission it's at the discretion of the official, idk and I can't say if that requirement is strongly enforced or not. Updated my A, hope it's clearer

Comment: To avoid the requirement for an air ticket out of contiguous territory an alternative plan might be to fly to Tijuana, cross the land border and travel to San Francisco from there. You'll pay $6 each for the paper I-94's, but the conversation will be more about whether you can afford your travel and not (directly) about return tickets.

Comment: @Dennis Then they would be entering Mexico without a return ticket, which whilst not mandatory, could cause additional issues.  To quote Timatic again, "Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry."

Comment: @NateEldredge You would be quite unlucky to be denied entry as a *bona fide* European traveller, with onward tickets to Mexico and a plan for continued travel out of the continent. In my experience, CBP have bigger fish to fry than VWP leisure travellers.

Comment: @Calchas A European traveler without a visa is almost guaranteed to be denied boarding without a return ticket outside of North America.  CBP is irrelevant as you'll never get that far.

Comment: @Doc Respectfully, that is not my experience. I appreciate you could have had difficulties yourself but I think the phrasing “almost guaranteed” is far too strong. Most carriers I use do not worry about it, as soon as I say I'll be leaving on a separate ticket with a different airline in x days they lose interest in the conversation. JL I remember does ask for the onward ticket number sometimes but they are the exception. At the other end of the spectrum BA usually doesn't even ask me about my onward plans.

Comment: @Calchas there is a legal requirement for those arriving by air to have a "round-trip" ticket, which is defined by regulation as a ticket that will take the traveler out of North America. The regulation doesn't actually require a literal round-trip ticket where the departure is on the same ticket as the arrival, so a different ticket with a different carrier qualifies. See https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.2. BA probably doesn't usually ask about your onward plans because you probably usually have a BA ticket that meets the requirement.